# Lookup value within a column and change outcome depending on criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365

**Background:**

- In Column A I have lists of main materials (Capital letters)some are composed of sub materials (lowercase) in column B.
- In column C I have numbered the 'pure' materials. An Item is 'pure' simply if it inst composed of other items so this can be either a raw materials or a sub component.
- Column D sorts the Main materials and the sub materials in a specific order.

[image]

**Aim:**
In Column F I wish to create a list of values that correspond to the materials in column D. For materials which are not 'pure' however I wish to insert a hyphen.

**What I've done So Far:**
Initially I used the formula:
`=XLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20)` but as shown in the image I get an N/A error because the main materials are not found in this list.

Subsequently Ive used
`=XLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20,XLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$A$20,$C$3:$C$20))`. This is better but returns values for all materials if they are pure or not.

So essentially so far I have achieved being able to lookup column D values in column B and if it fails then lookup the value in column A. I now just wonder if its possible to have a logical test that inserts a hyphen for non pure materials. The desired output is shown in column H.

If anyone thinks this can be done either via my approach of my a completley different approach I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so based on what you already have, I took the formulas from F3 and F4 (the latter being the same as F3 but with adjusted references), and put those in an IF:

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(D4,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20,XLOOKUP(D4,$A$3:$A$20,$C$3:$C$20))=XLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20,XLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$A$20,$C$3:$C$20)), "-", XLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20,XLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$A$20,$C$3:$C$20)))
```

Readability is, as you can see, quite poor though

Comment: Hi, yeah I did try something similar like:

`=IF(F3=F4,"-",XLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20,XLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$A$20,$C$3:$C$20)))` but this is a circular reference. I appreciate that it can be done in a separate column although I would like to try and keep it all in a single column. (sorry my comment entered too soon)

Comment: Another way to put it is I would like to perform a logical test following `=XLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$B$20,$C$3:$C$20)`. I'm just finding this tricky.

Comment: So besides being ugly and unreadable, is the current version fully functional? My apologies if I don't understand something

Comment: Works well. Thank you.